# Android application import com.google.api.services.prediction.*

Tags: android

I have a android application, I am trying to use Google prediction API.
I import google-api-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar, but it seems not work.
Actually, I put all libs/jar that from google-api-java-client-1.15.0-rc.zip, Credential/OAuth related seems OK now, but prediction API seems still got compile error.

Any suggestion ?
Any other jar files I have to import ?

Ex.
private static void train(Prediction prediction) throws IOException { ... }
Prediction cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Has the library been added to the build path?

Comment: Yes, I add all libraries to the build path.

Comment: I just download google-api-services-prediction-v1.6-rev3-java-1.15.0-rc
from 
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/prediction/v1.6/java.

And unzip this files, put google-api-services-prediction-v1.6-rev3-1.15.0-rc.jar into my libs foler, it fix most problem except one thing.

I still got "The import com.google.api.services.prediction.model.Training cannot be resolved".

Did I got wrong version ?